# Windows 2003 R2 DFS: Replicate Root but not links?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, dfs

I'm looking to set up a new AD DFS root.

Let's say I have three domain controllers: **dc01, dc02, dc03** and I have two storage servers: **srv01, srv02**. Each storage server contains *different* data and will not be relicated to the other storage server. I would like to build something like this:

- ROOT

  - link_to_srv01
  - link_to_srv02

Easy enough. It asks me for the server name that will serve the root. Let's say it's **dc01**. Now, here's the part I'm a little less clear on: I'd like **dc02** and **dc03** to replicate the ROOT so if any of the **dcXX** servers are taken off-line, the ROOT is still accessible--users can still get to the namespace that will point them to the links redirecting them to **srv01** and **srv02**.

Is something like this possible? Replicating the base root while not replicating the links to the storage servers?

Comment: Cheekaleak got it - I do something similar in my current environment.  The DFS root contains all our remote site fileshares, which are obviously different and don't replicate over each other, but if any of our DCs go down, there's a bunch of others that can serve up access to DFS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is add Dc02 and DC03 as `Namespace Servers`.  This will enable them to host the namespace you create (ROOT).  If DC01 is down, users will still be able to access the files via the namespace.

You can add them via the DFS Management console by clicking your root namespace and selecting `Add Namespace Server`.  Follow the wizard that opens to add the two other DCs.

Comment: Thanks, Cheek.

I'm running W2k3 and don't see the "Add Namespace Server" option. What I did was add a "New Root Target..." and selected each dc. I checked "Publish this root in Active Directory". Now, I should be able to add "New Link"s without the links actually replicating. Thanks again.